# AttributeError at /mobile/7/delete/ 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

I am trying to delete an item from my project but it gives error. interestingly it is deleting the item but gives error mention above.

views.py:

```
def delete_mobile(request, mobile_id):
    mobile1 = get_object_or_404(Mobile, pk=mobile_id).delete()
    form = MobileForm(instance=mobile1)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.delete()
        return redirect('mobile')
    return render(request, 'device/delete_mobile.html', {'mobile': mobile1})
```

delete_mobile.html:

```
{% extends 'device/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
   <form action="{% url 'delete_mobile' mobile.instance.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Delete {{ header }}:</h3>
    {{ mobile|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Delete</button>
   </form>
```

{% endblock %}

urls.py:

```
 path('mobile/<str:mobile_id>/delete/', views.delete_mobile, name='delete_mobile'),
```

Comment: Are you sure you dont have a comma `,` at the end of your `ModelForm`? i.e. `model = Mobile,`

Comment: nope there is not comma at the end of ModelForm.

Comment: can you upload your form file as well. the error might be there

Comment: everything is fine in form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, the problem was occurring due to repetition of .delete() method in my delete view.
now I have fixed it and working properly.

```
def delete_mobile(request, mobile_id):
    mobile1 = get_object_or_404(Mobile, pk=mobile_id)
    form = MobileForm(instance=mobile1)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.delete()
        return redirect('mobile')
    return render(request, 'device/delete_mobile.html', {'mobile': mobile1})
```